# Excel macros (change value of the cell selected if grater than or less than)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a task to be done and it is so time consuming, search some solutions but it won't work.

I have this workbook that needs to be edited in every cell. 
If I select the range like B2 to B8, and its contents are

`B2 = 70, B3 = 75, B4 = 80, B5 = 85, B6 = 90, B7 = 95, B8 = 100`

and conditions are if cell is `<=100 but >=96 =A, <=95 but >=91 =B, <=90 but >=86 =C, <=85 but >=81 =D, <=80 but >=76 = E, <=75 but >=71 =F And <=70 =G.`

So each cell will change to for example `B2 = 70` now it will change to 70(G) with "()".

And So B2 to B8

`B2 = 70(G), B3 = 75(F), B4 = 80(E), B5 = 85(D), B6 = 90(C), B7 = 95(B), B8 = 100(A)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your values selected run this macro:

```
Sub transform()
Dim v, a As String
For Each v In Selection
 Select Case v
  Case Is <= 70
   a = "G"
  Case Is <= 75
   a = "F"
  Case Is <= 80
   a = "E"
  Case Is <= 85
   a = "D"
  Case Is <= 90
   a = "C"
  Case Is <= 95
   a = "B"
  Case Is <= 100
   a = " A"
 End Select
 v.Value = v & "(" & a & ")"
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Solved. i cant vote for iam new here. so, I cant say thanks as well. cheers!